# Is it ok to sort a List in the body of the test case to check for boundary data?

Tags: java, integration-testing

I'm testing the results of a query. The table where the results are stored has a structure like this:

```
Id  SomeValue  Date        Hour
-----------------------------------
1   foo1       2015-01-01  700
2   foo2       2015-01-01  800
3   foo3       2015-01-01  900
...
18  foo18      2015-01-01  2400
19  bar1       2015-01-02  100
20  bar2       2015-01-02  200
...
41  bar23      2015-01-02  2300
42  bar24      2015-01-02  2400
43  baz1       2015-01-03  100
44  baz2       2015-01-03  200
(and on...)
```

And the query receives parameters in order to do the search based on `Date` and `Hour` columns like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    (date, hour) >= (:dateFrom, :hourFrom)
    AND (date, hour) <= (:dateTo, :hourTo)
-- there's no ORDER BY clause in the query
```

For example, if I use the following values:

- `dateFrom` : '2015-01-01'
- `hourFrom` : 700
- `dateTo` : '2015-01-03'
- `hourTo` : 600

The query will return all rows where the value of `Date` is between `2015-01-01` and `2015-01-03`, the values of `hour` are higher or equal than 700 only for `Date = 2015-01-01` and the values of `hour` are less or equal than 600 for `Date = 2015-01-03`. In this example, all the rows with `Date = 2015-01-02` will be retrieved from the data source.

I retrieve the results of the execution of the query in a list. In order to evaluate the results, I'm using the values of the parameters I've used to check if the data in the list complies with them. I'm using a method to check if the date of the element is between `dateFrom` and `dateTo`, but I'm wondering how can I test the values of `hourFrom` and `hourTo`. I have the following ideas:

- Start checking for the minumum value of `hour` on the elements where the value of `Date` is equals to my `dateFrom` parameter and check if this value is equals to `hourFrom`. Do similar for `hourTo` but with the maximum value of those rows where value of `Date` is equals to `dateTo` parameter value.
- Sort the list in my test method by `Date` and `Hour`, then check the first and last elements in the list. The sort method to use will be obtained from the programming language I'm using.

Which option is correct to do? If none, what will be the best strategy to do it?. I'm using Java to write the tests, but this question is more focused on how to write the test method rather than the technology/framework to use. Also, I cannot modify the query to add an `ORDER BY` clause (that would ease lot of my work but is not feasible).

I'm concerned about best practice. I was thinking on sorting the data so I will make assertions on two elements but then I'm worrying if I also have to test the `Comparator` used for sorting because it may sort the list wrongly and my test will fail, while checking each element manually means using `if-else` statements for the assertions, and I'm not sure if that is a good practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see how your primary concern may be to write a unit test with the simplest logic possible.  Doing this would raise your confidence level that when the unit test reports a success or failure, that it really does mean that the query is returning good or bad results, and not that you coded a bug in the logic of your unit test.  It may not even matter to you to have the absolute best performance.

If this is your case, I propose using your very straight-forward option #1, where you simply check each date/time sequentially, and fail the unit test as soon as you encounter a date/time that is not within your min/max date/time.  But I would adjust the method of comparing 2 sets of date/times in the following way to keep the comparison logic very simple:

Concatenate and format every date/time into the following string format: `YYYY-MM-DD hhmm` (e.g.: `2015-01-01 0700`). In other words, your string is formatted with the required zero-padding such that it will always have a length of `15`.  Following this format precisely has the very convenient property that if you compare 2 such strings using the built-in `String.compareTo()` method, it will compare your dates accurately.

This then allows you to keep your logic very simple and readable. Here is an example of what this could look like (you didn't specify, so I'll assume that your date is a string, and the time is a number. But you can adjust to your actual types):

```
// starting boundary values
String dateFrom = "2015-01-01";
int hourFrom = 700;
String dateTo = "2015-01-03";
int hourTo = 600;

String formatString = "%s %04d"; // adjust as necessary.

String fromDateTime = String.format(formatString, dateFrom, hourFrom);
String toDateTime = String.format(formatString, dateTo, hourTo);

// execute query here

while (rs.next()) {
    String dateTime = String.format(formatString, rs.getString("date"), rs.getInt("hour"));

    if (fromDateTime.compareTo(dateTime) > 0 || toDateTime.compareTo(dateTime) < 0) {
        throw new Exception("fail unit test");
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems interesting and more useful than my current ideas. I'll test this tomorrow (currently Sunday 8 p.m. for me) and will let you know how it went. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the options you proposed are correct. The option where you sort the data will easier to implement.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with sorting the results after retrieving them. That is the approach I would take, but checking each row would work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a Date, better to use java Date objects;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class ATest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        String dateFrom = "2015-01-01";
        String dateTo = "2015-01-03";

        // those are actually string as i see.
        String hourFrom = "700";
        String hourTo = "600";


        Date from = str2Date(dateFrom, hourFrom);
        Date to = str2Date(dateTo, hourTo);

        Date any = new GregorianCalendar().getTime();

        // now testing any date using 'before' 'after'
        assert(any.after(from) && any.before(to));

        // or using compareTo
        assert(any.compareTo(from) > 0 && any.compareTo(to) < 0);

        // or simpy comparing epocs, i would use this
        long low = from.getTime();
        long high = from.getTime();

        assert( any.getTime() > low && any.getTime() < high);
    }

    private static Date str2Date(String date_input, String time_input) {

        // probably this is an overkill.
        while (time_input.length() < 4){
            time_input = "0" + time_input;
        }

        String parts[] = date_input.split("-");
        int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]); 
        int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]); 
        int date = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);

        int hourOfDay = Integer.parseInt(time_input.subSequence(0, 2).toString()); 
        int minute = Integer.parseInt(time_input.subSequence(2, 4).toString());  
        int second = 0;

        Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(year, month - 1, date, hourOfDay, minute, second);

        return cal.getTime();
    }
}
```

Sorting or not is not important for me (if number of elements in list is not very high).

Answer (score -1):

Go with option 1. As you traverse the data, record the maximum and minimum values. You could only traverse the list once. If your objective is just to find an existence of non compliant data, then it's possible that you may not finish the traversal to the end if you already find one. This is more efficient than sorting the list. The worst case is O(n).